# SQL where customer_id in (xx)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Could really use your help!

I have a query:

```
Select *
from Customers
Where Customer_id in (001,002,003)
```

...you get the idea.

My problem is, if there is no record for customer_id 003 for example, no record is displayed.
How can i display "003" and state that no record was found? I would prefer this than having no record display at all.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also `001` is the same as `1`. The leading zeroes don't do anything except for strings. `('001','002','003')`

Comment: I think you have to be a little more specific. The "*" there can mean anything and how do you want to state that no record was found? A text message or "NULL"? The "easy" way to get what you want is to do a "SELECT * FROM ... UNION ALL SELECT customer_id, NULL, ... WHERE customer_id not in ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for this sort of thing I have a function which takes a csv and returns a table for me.
Then I do something like the following.

```
-- this is creating the temporary table which would normally be created by a function.
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Customer_id int)
INSERT INTO @Temp(Customer_id)
SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @Temp(Customer_id)
SELECT 2
INSERT INTO @Temp(Customer_id)
SELECT 3

-- now do the select statement.
SELECT 
    T.Customer_id,
     C.*
FROM
    Customers C
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     @Temp T
ON
     T.Customer_id = C.Customer_id
```

This will then give you results whereby if the `C.Customer_id` is `NULL` then it is not an `Id` that exists in your `Customer` `table`.
This does the same job as @MartinSmith did, but is supported by most SQL server versions.

Comment: Thank you to everyone that tried to help. You guys are awesome. Im not as advanced as you guys, Secret Squirrel's solution seems the best for me for some reason. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user2952152 remember to mark which answer is the solution ;)
My answer is just an alternative to Martin Smiths, although I would wonder how you could make that more generic to fit multiple datasets, not just a 1 time use.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008+ you can use

```
SELECT V.Customer_id,
       C.*
FROM   (VALUES(1),
              (2),
              (3)) V(Customer_id)
       LEFT JOIN Customers C
         ON C.Customer_id = V.Customer_id
```

Non matching values will have `NULL` in the `C.Customer_id` column.

Comment: As I said in my comment within my answer, is there a way this could be changed to make it more "Generic" therefore not just for fixed set of values?

Comment: @SecretSquirrel - No. The question showed a fix set of values so my answer is based on that. For a generic set of values I'd use a table valued parameter rather than splitting a CSV.

Comment: never knew about those (table valued parameter), seem pretty cool. although seem to be only supported by T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can do something like this:

```
with vals as
 (SELECT '001' as val
    from dual
  union
  select '002'
    from dual
  union
  select '030' from dual)
select v.val, nvl(c.Customer_id, 'no Customer found') from vals v left join Customers c on c.Customer_id = v.val
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is query against a list of the customer IDs you want to look up (including those that may not exist) and then left join this with your `customers` table. Creating a temporary table of customer IDs that you want to query against is platform specific, but here is how I would do it in Oracle:

```
with customersToLookup as (
  select '001' as customer_id from dual union all
  select '002' as customer_id from dual union all
  select '003' as customer_id from dual
)
select    customersToLookup.customer_id,
          customers.*
from      customersToLookup
left join customers
on        customers.customer_id = customersToLookup.customer_id;
```

It's very unusual, in my experience, to run a query like this: RDBMs aren't meant to be used in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Im using SQL Server 2012 management studio. 001 is the same as 1, just an example. The * was just my attempt to simplify the query, all i need is customer_name in the select. THe union will work, but alas i need to search up to about 50 id's (from an excel list). is there a better way than typing a select statement 50 odd times? i dont mind if a text messgae or "null" displays

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution because of complexity and clearly not recommended for tables with a lot of rows, but.. I created 2 new temporary tables: #tempTab2(in which I saved the id's that have been sent) and #tempTabFinal (in which I saved the row coresponding to that ID if the ID exist, and a "not found message" if not).Here is a print screen to see if this is what you what to do, and the code (I used for test the 'questions' table, which has as columns: q_id and question - the actual question)
[image]

```
DECLARE @INSTR as VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @INSTR = '1,153,154,1555,111,'
DECLARE @SEPERATOR as VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
SET @SEPERATOR = ','
CREATE TABLE #tempTab2 (id int not null,question varchar(60))
CREATE TABLE #tempTabFinal(id varchar(40) not null,question varchar(60))

WHILE PATINDEX('%' + @SEPERATOR + '%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%' + @SEPERATOR + '%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO #tempTab2 (id,question) VALUES (@VALUE,'question')
END

DECLARE @INDEX INT
SET @INDEX = 1

WHILE (@INDEX <=5)
BEGIN
    IF((Select COUNT(*) FROM questions Where q_id=  (SELECT TOP 1 id from #tempTab2)) >0   )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TEMP as varchar (80)
        SET @TEMP = (Select question from questions where q_id = (SELECT TOP 1 id from #tempTab2))
        DECLARE @ID INT 
        SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 id from #tempTab2)

        Insert into #tempTabFinal Values(@ID,@Temp)

    END
    ELSE    
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NOTFND as Varchar(20)
        SET @NOTFND = (SELECT TOP 1 id from #tempTab2)
        Insert into #tempTabFinal Values('id ' +@NOTFND + ' Not found ','Not found')
    END

    DELETE TOP (1) from #tempTab2
    SET @INDEX = @INDEX + 1
END

Select * from #tempTabFinal
DROP TABLE #tempTab2
DROP TABLE #tempTabFinal
```